# How to find and print all parameters in files?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have multiple text files with parameters defined on it. Parameters would take the form of {{env.parameter_name}}. I need to do following with them using a bash script.

1. Find all parameters in files.
2. Print the parameter names.

What would be the best way?

My input file looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <host value="{{env.host}}" />
  <port value="{{env.port}}" />
</config>
```

And I want my output to be like this

```
{{env.host}}
{{env.port}}
```

Comment: best use `egrep` command with regex something like `egrep "{{env\..*?}}" fileName.txt`

Comment: @SMA egrep doesn't know about non-greedy matching, that's a PCRE construct.

Comment: Use a proper `XML` parser instead of text processing tools like `Awk` or `sed`, can you install `xmllint`?

Comment: If your string `{{...}}` can appear twice on 1 line then include that in your example as it requires a different solution than if it only occurs once. Ditto if `{{` or `}}` can occur in other contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following awk may help you in same, since you haven't shown any sample Input_file(s) so haven't tested it, kindly try it and let me know then.

```
awk 'FNR==1{if(val){print  RS "*******";close(val)};print "*******" RS FILENAME;val=FILENAME;} /{{.*}}/' *.txt
```

It should print the file names and then all parameters eg-->

```
*******
    file1.txt
    {{env.parameter_name}}
    {{env.other_name}}
*******
*******
    file2.txt
    {{test_name}}
*******
```

***EDIT:*** Since OP require only parameters to be printed then following may be helping in same.

```
awk 'FNR==1{if(val){close(val)};val=FILENAME;} /{{.*}}/{match($0,/{{.*}}/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' *.txt
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder, this helped! But I want the output to look like in the expected output in the question. I made few edits to add the input file. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I need exactly the parameter names.

Comment: @DunithDhanushka, could you please try my EDIT now and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: It's printing below lines. <host value="{{env.host}}" />
  <port value="{{env.port}}" /> Is there any way I can get values exactly similar to the output I posted? Maybe pipe your awk to another command?

Comment: Your awk expression had few syntax errors. After few edits, this worked for me awk '/{{.*}}/{match($0,/{{.*}}/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
If could edit your answer, then I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @DunithDhanushka, hmmm, sorry check now, was doing multitasking, it should work now, let me know on same.

Comment: @DunithDhanushka, Above solution will handle multiple files too, wanted to add it here like why I added little piece of code before match utility of awk.

Answer (score 2):

With xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet select --template --value-of '//@value' file.xml
```

Or get all attributes from file.xml:

```
xmlstarlet select --template --value-of '//@*' file.xml
```

In this case, output in both cases:

```
{{env.host}}
{{env.port}}
```

---

See: `xmlstarlet select --help`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'match($0,/\{{.*\}}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat infile
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <host value="{{env.host}}" />
  <port value="{{env.port}}" />
</config>

$ awk 'match($0,/\{{.*\}}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' infile
{{env.host}}
{{env.port}}
```

**Using grep:**

```
$ grep -Po '({{(?>([^}}])|(?0))*?}})' file
{{env.host}}
{{env.port}}
```

In case if you have multiple values like below,

```
$ cat file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <host value="{{env.host}}" />
  <port value="{{env.port}}{{env.etc}}" />
</config>

$ grep -Po '({{(?>([^}}])|(?0))*?}})' file
{{env.host}}
{{env.port}}
{{env.etc}}
```

Comment: This one looks like much cleaner!